# Is there a Settings/System Preferences simulator for macOS/iOS tech support?

Tags: software-recommendation, settings, system-settings

Frequently when offering technical assistance, I either want to follow along with my own instructions to make sure they are correct, or provide a screenshot to demonstrate my instructions visually. Often, it is sufficient to do so on my own device, but there are a number of problems that can come up with this method:

- If my device is running a different version of the operating system, what I see is likely different from what the user sees.
- If it is an area of Settings that shows sensitive information, I need to either use a Guest account without personal information or censor it later. The former is not possible on iOS without buying a dedicated device for it, and censoring images takes time.
- Getting a screenshot from an iOS device to my computer is fairly simple, but the time adds up when compared to doing the same on macOS.
- If there are device-specific settings, and I don't have a device with those capabilities (for example, none of my devices support Force/3D Touch), I won't be able to help.

Using Xcode's iOS Simulator is almost never a viable alternative, as its Settings app is greatly pared down and only includes a handful of options.

Does there exist some Mac app whose purpose is to simulate the Settings or System Preferences app of various devices and OS versions?